# Word to describe rebellion against one's god

Tags: single-word-requests

This is in the context of mythology, where the subject or the creation of a god tries to overthrow, challenge or directly assails the god.

Comment: One such word is *apostasy.*

Comment: Apostasy: the abandonment or renunciation of a religious or political belief.

I am looking for a word that describes not the discarding of a belief but the physical attack against a god, like Lucifer against the Christian god.

Comment: Sounds like a *rebellion* to me. I'm not sure there's a separate word for rebellion specifically against a god.

Comment: "defy" comes to mind. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Defy

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/heresy -- Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: *cough* G. H. Hardy *cough*

Comment: You're conflating modern ideas of God/Gods with ancient ones. A creation of Zeus doesn't HAVE a god. They are more like adolescents in that sense; they have a significant amount of control over their own destiny. A "rebellion against the creator" is probably what you're looking for. This actually a common theme in literature, I'm sure if you poke around some more you'll find something more concise than the phrase I have... "ad Deus" (against God) comes to mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a word that works well for the particular context in my writing: **Treason**

1. the offense of acting to overthrow one's government or to harm or
   kill its sovereign.
2. a violation of allegiance to one's sovereign or to one's state.
3. the betrayal of a trust or confidence; breach of faith; treachery.

Although there is nothing explicitly god-related in this, the things regarding "sovereign" seems appropriate for offense against a god. Beside, the word "treason" almost always have negative connotation, which would be appropriate when the action is described by those who believe in the god.

Comment: Well, there is the term *lèse majesté* for treason (or mere affronts) against a king. Maybe you could coin a phrase like *lèse divinité* or *lèse déité*?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use some expression like "insurrection against the heavenly throne". But if there was a single word for it, some author would surely have used it already to describe Lucifer's rebellion.

"[Deicide](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deicide?s=t)" could apply to the outcome of a successful attempt, and by analogy with *regicide* we might seek a "regi-" word that applies to an attempt to overthrow a king. If one existed, we could apply "dei-" to it. But I don't think there is one.

There are words like "mutiny", "rebellion", "revolt", "uprising" and so forth, but these apply to an action against any dictator or feudal overlord. There is no evident way to append a prefix to these to make them apply specifically to a king. And if we can't coin a single word for the far more common case involving a king, then it is hard to imagine that such a word exists for the much more specialized case involving a god.

Edit: by analogy with *lèse majesté*, you might coin a phrase like *lèse divinité* or *lèse déité*.

Comment: "lese divinite" very poetic

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

***blasphemy***

> (*Law*) the crime committed if a person insults, offends, or vilifies the deity, Christ, or the Christian religion.
>
> [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Blasphemy)

***defiance***

> : open or bold resistance to or disregard for authority, opposition, or power.
>
> [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/defiance)
>
> *A huge and powerful warrior-king who virtually embodies defiance against his highest god, Capaneus is an exemplary blasphemer--with blasphemy understood as direct violence against God. Still, it is striking that Dante selects a pagan character to represent one of the few specifically religious sins punished in hell.*
>
> [Danteworlds - The University of Texas](http://danteworlds.laits.utexas.edu/textpopup/inf1401.html)

Comment: There is nothing about a god in this answer - it is not god-specific.

Comment: @Drew: I'm pretty sure that _blasphemy_ is centrally about (as Elian's dictionary quotation indicates) insulting, offending, or vilifying the deity. In the seventh circle of the Inferno, Dante places blasphemers, including the remarkable figure [Capaneus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capaneus), who continues to defy  and curse Jove despite his eternal punishment in a rain of fire. (Of course, as Capaneus might argue, "It's not eternal yet!")

Comment: @SvenYargs: He added *blasphemy* after my comment about *defiance*. Instead of spending effort to document the history of blasphemy you might have checked the edit history. ;-)

Comment: @Drew: Not only did I not pay any attention to the edit history here, but also I didn't notice that the answer already covered Capaneus, who is one of my favorite characters in _The Divine Comedy_. Anyway, I apologize for misunderstanding the nature of and justification for your original comment.

Answer (score -2):

Unbenevalent actions towards a god. Basically unkind actions towards that God. It works well in your context of mythology or with any god because by committing an UNkind or unbenevalent act against them you are showing a sign of rebellion

Comment: This seems a little bit of a an understatement to me-- "unbenevolent" sound like being mean, not trying to overthrow or rebel against someone.